# Unexpected div created in SvelteKit

Tags: routes, sveltekit

I'm trying to use the new routing system in SvelteKit, and I get unexpected `div`. Basically in the DOM I get

```
<body>
   <div> \\---> unexpected
      <div class="container">
         <h1>Hello<h1/>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

I use the default routing files, where I put

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Hello<h1/>
</div>
```

in +page.svelte

and in +layout.svelte I have

```
<slot/>
```

Both +page.svelte and +layout.svelte are directly under the routes folder.

Where is the first `div` coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `app.html` has an additional `div`:

```html
<body>
    <div style="display: contents">%sveltekit.body%</div>
</body>
```

Maybe it is this one?